# unable to send data from android to php

Tags: android, http-post

i was trying to upload data from my android app to php but, i am not receiving the data at the server.i tried echoing the data, can any one help with this code,i am not getting any error

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("trip_id",x));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loc_lat",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loc_lon",String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())));
                HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://xx/x.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
```

Comment: are you able to get the data in php script??

Comment: no iam not able to get the data in the php script

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this one. I'm comparing your code with mine, but I remember that the problem was the server redirecting me wasn't sending the POSTrequest. I had to type the IP of the website and use GET method.
Try using

```
HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("x.x.x.x");
```

Even though it's not a solution (except if your server has a fixed IP), it could help finding the problem.